# What Chinese fonts can I rely on to be in Mac and Linux?

Tags: fonts, linux, cjk, mac

See [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185817/chinese-typing-on-mac/193333?noredirect=1#comment506001_193333);  I am involved in a project that needs to have (automatic) XeLaTeX compilation of various language files on both Mac and Linux (usually Fedora or Debian or Ubuntu), and apparently the default fonts are not at all the same.  Is there anything I can do to ensure this kind of portability without asking the user to install new fonts?

Currently apparently this works on Fedora:

```
\usepackage[noindent,UTF8]{ctexcap}
\setCJKmainfont{AR PL UMing CN}
\setCJKsansfont{WenQuanYi Zen Hei}
\setCJKmonofont{WenQuanYi Zen Hei Mono}
```

but I needed to change to e.g.

```
\setCJKmainfont[BoldFont=STHeiti,ItalicFont=STKaiti]{STSong}
\setCJKsansfont[BoldFont=STHeiti]{STXihei}
\setCJKmonofont{STFangsong}
```

(from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193333/11532)) though I know that Mac has lots of other Chinese fonts available too.

Ideally, there would be a solution with some sort of fallback option, but I don't know anything about xecjk (or cjk, for that matter) and in any case that option (as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174600/why-doesnt-my-chinese-character-display-properly)) seems to be more related to when *characters* are not present in a font, not when a *font* isn't present.

Thanks!

Comment: Does it matter whether the documents produced look the same?

Comment: No (well, within reason).  What matters is having one codebase that can be run on various systems.  I mean, we don't want a totally crappy font, but otherwise that is much secondary - it's documentation which otherwise doesn't have that much presentation value in any case.

Comment: For posterity, Wikipedia’s [List of CJK fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CJK_fonts) contains various freely available ones.

Answer (score 13):

### Portable, and consistent solution

> Fandol fonts are reliable portable fonts for typesetting Simplified Chinese in TeX.

Fandol fonts are not perfect: compared to the other commercial fonts, the character set of Fandol fonts is somewhat restricted, and the puncuations need to be tuned.

Luckily, Fandol is a complete series of Chinese fonts in OpenType format, and well designed for typesetting.

[image]

```
% !TEX program = XeLaTeX
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass[UTF8,nofonts]{ctexart}
\setCJKmainfont[BoldFont=FandolSong-Bold.otf,ItalicFont=FandolKai-Regular.otf]{FandolSong-Regular.otf}
\setCJKsansfont[BoldFont=FandolHei-Bold.otf]{FandolHei-Regular.otf}
\setCJKmonofont{FandolFang-Regular.otf}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
 & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Series/Shape} \\ \cline{2-4}
Family & \verb=\mdseries= & \verb=\bfseries= & \verb=\mdseries\itshape= \\ \hline
\verb=\rmfamily= & 宋体 & \textbf{粗宋体} & \textit{楷体} \\
\verb=\sffamily= & \textsf{黑体} & \textsf{\textbf{粗黑体}} & \\
\verb=\ttfamily= & \texttt{仿宋体} &&\\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The problem is, **most Chinese fonts are expensive commercial ones**, you simply have little choice for *free Chinese fonts*. And what's more, Fandol font bundle is *the only choice* preinstalled in TeX Live (or MacTeX, MiKTeX) if you use XeTeX or LuaTeX. Therefore, it is now the only portable way to typesetting Simplified Chinese documents in TeX.

Yes there are also Arphic fonts, but only subfonts for `CJK` package in Type1 format are provided in TeX distributions. Only two families (`gbsn` and `gkai`) for Simplified Chinese, or two corresponding families (`bsmi` and `bkai`) for Traditional Chinese are provided by Arphic.

### Some sort of fallback option for rare glyphs?

**No.** We don't have enough fonts available for that.

Now we have some good free fonts for large character sets. For example the [Souce Han Sans](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-han-sans/) fonts. But they are pre-installed neither in TeX distributions, nor in operation systems.

### Something native?

Yes it is possible. In the [developer version](https://code.google.com/p/ctex-kit/source/browse/#svn%2Fbranches%2Fctex) (ver 2.x) of `ctex` package, we defined several different font sets, and the package will detect the operation system and select a native font set if you wish.

- SinoType fonts are automatically selected for Mac.
- ZhongYi fonts are automatically selected for Windows.
- Fandol fonts are automatically selcted otherwise. (No, we don't use the incomplete Arphic fonts as default fonts, let alone WenQuanYi.)

And we do provide options to select Arphic and WenQuanYi fonts (`fontset=ubuntu` option), there are also options for Adobe fonts and Founder fonts.

Comment: Interesting.  But what versions of TeX Live is it in?  `The font "FandolSong-Regular" cannot be found.`  Ideally we would have a solution that did not require a user to upgrade their TeX distro just to build the documentation.

Comment: @kcrisman: TeX Live 2014 is fine. You should use the [TeX Live from TUG](http://www.tug.org/texlive/), not the `texlive-***` packages for Debian or Ubuntu, which are incomplete TeX live.
The files are located at `texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/fandol`.
If you do have the fonts but you just cannot compile: one possible problem is how `fontspec` (I mean XeTeX) find your font file. You should use the file name (with `.otf`) of the fonts to force XeTeX to find the fonts via `kpathsea` library.

Comment: @kcrisman: For Linux, you should also follow the instructions in section 3.4.4 of TeX Live 2014 document: [*3.4.4 System font configuration for XeTeX and LuaTeX*](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-340003.4.4). This helps the `fontconfig` library to find the fonts.

Comment: @kcrisman: I'm afraid that Fandol fonts were released *after* TeX Live 2013 released. The initital version, w.r.t README, is on 2013/07/31.

Comment: My point is what if someone doesn't have TeX Live 2014?  Is there *any* other font set that earlier tex distros would have in common for (simplified) Chinese?  Or any fonts that Mac and (some versions of) Linux would have in common by default?  Apparently Simsun and company are not allowed because of license (though Mac has these Windows products!).

Comment: @kcrisman: NO, noway. I'm afraid. That's why it is difficult for us -- for years -- to develop a portable `ctex` bundle. BTW, the Chinese fonts installed in Linux is a mess.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your update.  Yes, I noticed the Linux mess.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'the Chinese fonts installed in Linux'. Linux is just the kernel. Distributions differ. (Mine would not provide Chinese fonts 'by default' at all.)

Comment: @cfr: I mean, Linux distribuitons -- or the package repositories of most popular Linux desktop distributions. Anyway, you know what I mean.

Comment: Yes, but I think that saying it in that way is pernicious! ;)

Comment: http://bohoomil.com/ might be of interest although I don't know anything about Chinese so cannot evaluate its support for that. (But the software gets improved effectively and extremely rapidly in response to people pointing out gaps or problems.)

Comment: That was actually my bad for encouraging such talk (and don't you mean GNU/Linux distros?) - though elsewhere I do give *examples* of what I meant.  I think if there was something in common between Fedora, Debian, Ubuntu, and Mac it would be nice.

Comment: Hi!  Sorry for the long thread - I want to accept this, but even with TeX Live 2014 I am having trouble with it, definitely need the `nofonts` option.  I get ` fontspec warning: "script-not-exist"` and `Font 'FandolSong-Regular.otf' does not contain script 'CJK'.`.  It does compile (this is a fairly complicate thing that runs through Sphinx, but I am using `\usepackage[noindent,UTF8,nofonts]{ctexcap}` if that helps.

Comment: Weirdly, I get things like `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/FandolFang-Regular.otf(0)/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `EU1/FandolFang-Regular.otf(0)/m/n' instead on input 
line 325.`

Comment: @kcrisman: It's fine. Configure your editor/IDE/library/script to ignore the warnings. It is common that not all NFSS shapes are defined for Chinese, since there is no concept of *italic* or *slanted* in Chinese typesetting. And it is common that not all OpenType features (e.g. 'CJK' script) are supported for a specific font.